# MySQL query inserts null value in the Database in C#

Tags: c#, mysql, insert, null

I have a C# application that stores a client's information. I'm using MySQL  Workbench as the backend. Now when ever I insert data into the db (via various controls on my form), the primary key (client_file_no) is auto incremented but the rest of the fields show "NULL". I have checked the code over and over but I still cannot find the error.

```
    try
            {
                ConnectionDBLabData cdld = new ConnectionDBLabData();
                string ConnStr = cdld.GetConnectionString();
                MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(ConnStr);
                conn.Open();
                string QueryString = "insert into client_tbl (client_date_of_creation, client_referral_code, client_first_name, client_middle_name, client_last_name, client_sex, client_nationality, client_status, client_civil_id , client_birthday, client_born_year , client_preferred_language, client_occupation , client_email, client_tel_mobile, client_tel_home1, client_tel_home2, client_tel_work1,client_tel_work2, client_address1, client_address2, client_notes, client_cc , client_credit, client_debit, client_debitmax, client_stat, client_pricetype, client_qr_path ) VALUES(@value1, @value2, @value3 ,@value4, @value5 ,@value6, @value7, @value8, @value9 ,@value10 ,@value11, @value12, @value13, @value14, @value15, @value16, @value17, @value18, @value19, @value20, @value21, @value22, @value23, @value24, @value25, @value26, @value27, @value28, @value29)";
                MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(QueryString, conn);
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@value1", textBox21.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@value2", textBox23.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@value3", textBox1.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@value4", textBox2.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@value5", textBox3.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@value6", Convert.ToString(comboBox4.SelectedItem));
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@value7", Convert.ToString(comboBox2.SelectedItem));
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@value8", Convert.ToString(comboBox1.SelectedItem));
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@value9", textBox5.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@value10", textBox13.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@value11", textBox19.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@value12", textBox22.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@value13", textBox6.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@value14", textBox7.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@value15", textBox8.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@value16", textBox9.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@value17", textBox10.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@value18", textBox11.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@value19", textBox12.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@value20", richTextBox1.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@value21", richTextBox2.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@value22", richTextBox3.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@value23", textBox4.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@value24", Convert.ToDouble(textBox14.Text));
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@value25", Convert.ToDouble(textBox15.Text));
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@value26", Convert.ToDouble(textBox16.Text));
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@value27", Convert.ToInt32(textBox17.Text));
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@value28", Convert.ToInt32(textBox18.Text));
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@value29", textBox5.Text + "_qr.png");
                cmd.ExecuteScalar();
```

And the database:

```
    create table client_tbl(client_file_no int not null auto_increment primary key,
                            client_date_of_creation varchar(20),
                            client_referral_code varchar(60), 
                            client_first_name varchar(20),
                            client_second_name varchar(20),
                            client_last_name varchar(20),
                            client_nationality varchar(60),
                            client_sex varchar(10),
                            client_status varchar(20),
                            client_civil_id varchar(30),
                            client_birthday varchar(20), 
                            client_born_year varchar(20),
                            client_occupation varchar(30),
                            client_preferred_language varchar(30),
                            client_email varchar(40), 
                            client_tel_mobile varchar(20),
                            client_tel_work1 varchar(20),
                            client_tel_work2 varchar(20),
                            client_tel_home2 varchar(20),
                            client_address1 varchar(512), 
                            client_address2 varchar(512), 
                            client_notes varchar(512),
                            client_cc  varchar(50), 
                            client_credit float,
                            client_debit float, 
                            client_debitmax float, 
                            client_stat int,
                            client_pricetype int, 
                            client_rq_code varchar(80));
```

Comment: What are the values of the text boxes? As a suggestion I would try and name your parameters properly, as well as your text boxes.

Comment: Did you get any exception? From your code above is not clear what happen in case of exceptions. And try to use ExecuteNonQuery for an insert command....

Comment: I try to run you code with Xampp tool. Everything is normal.
Have you used Immidiate Windows to debug and view all values of all parameters? I think you should check their's values. Some of them may be wrong datatype.

Comment: All the data types are right. If I am not wrong, 1-2 fields may be wrong (with respect to their data types) but atleast the rest of the fields(string values) should work right!

Comment: There was an issue with my connector. I changed it and everything is working. Thanks everyone

Answer (score 1):

Try AddWithValue

```
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@value1", textBox21.Text);
```

Comment: Hello, When I use AddWithValue() this is the error that I get. Do I have to import some additional package? 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlParameterCollection' does not contain a definition for 'AddWithValue' and no extension method 'AddWithValue' accepting a first argument of type 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlParameterCollection' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: @KshitijThube this should not be possible with the latest versions of the MySql Connector. What version do you use of the connector? Or do you use a differente ADO.NET provider for MySql?

Comment: Finally! My connector was "FAULTY" that caused all the error. Thanks everyone for your help.

Comment: `AddWithValue` was [added in v5.0.5](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/connector-net/en/connector-net-news-5-0-5.html) of the MySql connector - which version are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Solved the issue by changing my connector(turns out my connector was faulty)
Thanks everyone for your help
Regards,
Kshitij Thube